# Angular.js JSONP callback request issue with Symfony2

Tags: angularjs, json, symfony

My App which has just gone live for some reason worked fine during the testing phase but just broke when published on Google play.

I am submitting information to my server eg. logging in through angular.js json requests which used to work but now, I am getting an invalid callback name error in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php at line 77.

```
The callback name is not valid.
```

The issue emanates from the callback string attached by angular.js

```
&callback=angular.callbacks._0
```

Even though my URL is constructed like this:

```
url = serviceBase + q + '?' + obj.serialize(object) + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
```

This is how I handle response in symfony action

```
$response = new JsonResponse();    
$response->setCallback($callback);
$response->setData($feedback);
return $response;
```

Is there any way this could be remedied? I tried looking around and googling but there was no definitive answer that was not a hack. Thanks in advance, I hope someone will help me before anyone wakes up and tries to register or logs in